# Ampersand not displaying in page title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an application where a company name - like "Foo & Bar" is part of the title on some pages.  I have tried changing the data to be `&amp;`, I have tried `html_safe`, but no luck.

I could change the `&` to `and` but I would prefer to preserve the name of the company as the user entered it.

What easy and magical Ruby (1.9.2)/Rails (3) goodness am I missing?

Comment: Can you show us some code so we can try to replicate your error?

Comment: What does it display? Have you tried looking at the HTML source to see where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I figured it out.  I had used an adaptation of Ryan Bates Pretty Page Title (episode 30) and I was calling `html_safe` in the wrong place.